# Randomising a past date from today, but not going past a set date

Tags: php

This is what I am trying to achieve. Setting a past date of -3 days from today, but having this rotate between -3, -2 or -1 days, but never going back in the past. E.g.

Today: 08/02/2022
Result of -3 days: 05/02/22

Next day: 09/02/2022
Result of -2 days: 07/02/22

etc

```
$today           = strtotime(date('d-m-Y'));
$maxDaysInPast = strtotime(date('d-m-Y', strtotime('-3 day')));

$result = date('d/m/Y', mt_rand($threeDaysInPast, $today));

var_dump($result);
```

I am trying to achieve a random past date for each day, but not go past -3 days.

Comment: It looks like the code you have there would do that, other than the variable name mismatch (`$maxDaysInPast` vs. `$threeDaysInPast`).

Comment: I think if you showed the results of two more days, so we could understand the rotation rule a little better, would be very helpful.

Comment: If the return has been 09/02/2022 , it can't go back past 09/02/2022

Answer (score 1):

If you're only concerned with the day part, it would be simpler to just randomize the number you pass to `strtotime()` instead.

```
$result = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-' . mt_rand(1, 3) . ' day'));
```